# Perturbation expansion in bound scattering states for double Dirac barriers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory, dirac-delta-distributions

I was working my way through scattering theory notes by David Tong.In there,he discusses the analytical property of the $S$-matrix and uses it for the resonance states for the *Double - Dirac* potential barrier. The potential is :
$$V(x) = U(\delta(x-1) + \delta(x+1) )$$
In order to see the bound states he sets the Denominator of $S++$ coefficient to zero and gets the following-Equation (1):
$$\exp{2ik} = -1 + i2k/U .$$
In the limit, $U$ goes to infinity ,the values of $k$ are:
$$k= (n+ 1/2)\pi$$
After this, he says that when $U$ is very large but finite we can expand *Equation (1)* in powers of $1/U$ for $n=0$.

How do we go about doing this? What I did was to solve for the transcendental equation:
$$Sin(k) = 2k/U $$
I get a value of $k$ slightly less than $\pi$,which I can calculate by Taylor's theorem.

The value comes out to be, 
$$k = \pi -(2\pi)/(1+U)$$
Clearly, my method didn't give any complex $K$ values. Can anyone explain?